# Webscraping ranked volume data from opensea stats pages

Tags: web-scraping, nft, opensea

I'm trying to get rankings data for NFT collections sorted by their highest all-time volume. It seems that currently the opensea API does not support ranked lists as an endpoint. As a workaround, I'm looking at web-scraping to fetch the all-time volume rankings information using https://opensea.io/rankings?sortBy=total_volume.

However, I am having difficultly fetching data for any entry in the rankings list past a 100 items - i.e. page 2 of the rankings and onwards. The opensea url does not explicitly change when I click on the list of ranks at the bottom of the page (101-201).

Any ideas on how I could automate web scraping for ranks past the first 100 entries?

I'd appreciate any help here. And thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: Hi! Did you figure this out yet? Is there another solution than scraping?

Answer (score 0):

Did you check out this library that does scraping for you under the hood? I have tested some endpoints and it appears to return data. Please check out: https://github.com/dcts/opensea-scraper

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thanks Usman. I had a look but it seems that the above project does not return any data concerning nft rankings which is what I was interested in.